# Iterating Through A vector To Identify Paragraphs

Tags: c++, vector, loops

I have now entered a section of a book (C++ Primer 5th Edition) that deals with iterators. So far it seems fairly simple, but I am having a few small challenges.

In the book the question asks "...Change the elements in *text* [a vector] that correspond to the first paragraph to all uppercase and print its contents."

The first problem I have is that on Page 110 of the book it gives example code to use in order to identify whether the vector has an empty element in it denoting the end of a paragraph. The code is as follows, from the book:

```
// print each line in text up to the first blank line
    for (auto it = text.cbegin(); it != text.cend() && !it->empty(); ++it);
    cout << *it << endl;
```

However, when I type this in to the editor I get an error referring to *it saying: Use of undeclared identifier 'it'.

If I want to create a vector *text* and read in elements from an input, then run an iterator to check to see if there is an end of paragraph, and then capitalise the entire paragraph and print the result, how would I do so?

I thought I knew, but as soon as I put in the example code, it gave the above error.

Here's the code I put up (before doing any capitalisation I wanted to test if it could read a paragraph) and was playing with, but all this does is print the last word typed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::string; using std::vector; using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;

int main ()
{
    const vector<string> text;
    string words;

    while (cin >> words) {
        for (auto it = text.cbegin(); it != text.cend() && !it->empty(); ++it);
    }
    cout << words << endl;
}
```

Your help, as always, is appreciated!

Comment: see http://ideone.com/MPbYdR, it just compile file

Comment: The latest version of `MinGW` compiler certainly doesn't support `auto` variables.

Comment: First, please post the actual code that is creating the error, since I don't see any `cout << *it << endl;` line anywhere.
Second, post the full error with a reference to the line causing it.
Third, @ValekHalfHeart is probably right about the errant semi-colon.
Finally, make sure `auto` is supported by your compiler.

Comment: @Aposperite: Yes it does.  Add `-std=c++0x` or `-std=c++11` to the command line.

Comment: @moswald The code that was creating the error was the first block I put in the question where line 3 had the "cout << *it << endl; I went ahead and tried to generate alternative code because of the problem it had with the example code, but even what I thought would maybe be an alternative didn't work. The compiler I am using is Xcode and yes, it definitely supports auto and all C++11 functions. Unfortunately it doesn't include line numbers for code, so it is a bit of a pain having to count all the lines to identify which line number caused the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring the iterator local to the for loop, but you put a semicolon after your loop, so the line `cout << *it << endl;` is not part of your loop and the variable `it` is not in scope. simply remove the semicolon and you will be fine:

```
 for (auto it = text.cbegin(); it != text.cend() && !it->empty(); ++it)//no semicolon here
    cout << *it << endl;
```

To better illustrate what was happening, here is a pair of examples with braces:

```
 //your original code:
 for (auto it = text.cbegin(); it != text.cend() && !it->empty(); ++it)
 {

 }
 cout << *it << endl; //variable it does not exist after the for loop ends

 //code that works:
 for (auto it = text.cbegin(); it != text.cend() && !it->empty(); ++it)
 {
          cout << *it << endl; //what happens _unless_ you put a ; after the loop statement
 }
```

I don't know if this solves your entire question but it should fix the error you were getting.

Comment: Such a simple thing! Now that I see that works, I will try and write up some code referring to the inputting of a paragraph in to a vector, and I will post the result here, whether it works or not. I might need further assistance later. Thanks!! This syntax thing is sometimes a challenge.

Comment: Ok, so now that that bit of code works I have new code (below). This one does not seem to differentiate between paragraphs though? If I add text in the input, then 2 blank lines, and more text, it just concatenates it all into one paragraph? I also can't get the topper to work either (line 8). `int main ()
{
    vector<string> text;
    string words;
    
    while (cin >> words) {
        text.push_back(words);
    }
    for (auto it = text.cbegin(); it != text.cend() && !it->empty(); ++it)
        *it = toupper(*it)
        cout << *it << " ";
}`

Comment: Ummm, Ok, sorry, all the code just went out as one. Don't know how to change it...

Answer (score 0):

I worked through the same problem and was able to convert the elements of the first paragraph to uppercase, then print the contents, by adding a ranged for loop. See code below.

```
// Exercise_3.22.cpp : Revise the loop that printed the first paragraph in text to instead change the elements in text that correspond to the first paragraph to all uppercase. After you've updated text, print its contents.

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

#include <vector>
using std::vector;

#include <string>
using std::string;

int main()
{
    vector<string> text;        // holds the input

    string s;
    while (getline(cin, s))     // read the entire input file
    {
        text.push_back(s);      // storing each line as an element in text
    }

    // change the elements in text that correspond to the first paragraph to all uppercase
    // print each line in text up to the first blank line
    for (auto iter = text.begin(); iter != text.end() && !iter->empty(); iter++)
    {
        for (auto &s : *iter)
        {
            s = toupper(s);
        }
        cout << *iter << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```